# How to check if json array has any value?

Tags: android, json

I am using the condition -

```
if (!obj2.getString("patronCheckoutInfo").equals("null")) {
```

But it does not work for the case when array got the value.

Eg: Case1- when json got value for "patronCheckoutInfo":

```
{
"ErrorMessage": ""
"Message": "Operation completed successfully"
"Status": "OK"
"Results": {
"LookupPatronInfoResponse": {
"patronAddressInfo": null
"patronCheckoutHistoryInfo": null
"patronCheckoutInfo": [6]
0:  {
"author": "Cobb, Kevin."
```

Case 2 - when no value:

```
{
"ErrorMessage": ""
"Message": "Operation completed successfully"
"Status": "OK"
"Results": {
"LookupPatronInfoResponse": {
"patronAddressInfo": null
"patronCheckoutHistoryInfo": null
"patronCheckoutInfo": null
"patronCirculationInfo": null
```

Tried few tutorials but unable to figure out. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `optJSONArray(String name)` returns value if it exists or null otherwise

Comment: Try checking like `if (!obj2.getString("patronCheckoutInfo") == null)`... Because `null` is not a string to check like that...

Comment: does it works for you

Comment: @Raghunandan please convert this into an answer. I'm sure that it will solve OPs question

Comment: optJSONArray(String name) --> shows null pointer exception

Comment: @Dep did you do the following? JSONArray array = obj2.optJsonArray("patronCheckoutInfo); if(array == null) {blah}

Comment: If(array == null) {//no value} else {//Has value, you can use the array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestion. Below worked for me:

```
if (obj2.getString("patronCheckoutInfo") != null)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use support function `isNull` (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String))

So, re-write your code in this case:

```
if (!obj2.isNull("patronCheckoutInfo")) {
// do something 
}
```

Comment: also you might use [has()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29), but question author have this field in both JSONs

Comment: @snachmsm but the document said `Returns true if this object has no mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.` In this case, both json response had this key, so if in case of the value of second json response had NULL value, it should return `true`. Right?

Comment: This condition is returning - false - even for values in patronCheckoutInfo. Not working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check if the particular key present in the Json.

Its pretty simple..!! 
Try this..

```
boolean response = jsonobject.has("patronCheckoutInfo")
```

Hope this will help you,
Happy coding

Comment: it will return true in both cases.

Comment: you need to specify the jsonobject that contains the particular key.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
if(obj2.has("patronCheckoutInfo")){
//write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if (!obj2.getString("patronCheckoutInfo").equals("null"))
```

to

```
String patronCheckoutInfo = obj2.getString("patronCheckoutInfo");
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(patronCheckoutInfo)){
  // string has value
}else{
  // string is empty
}
```

Comment: Its empty but still going into the loop. Not working.

Comment: patronCheckoutInfo got no values - but condition results in true.

Comment: print out the `patronCheckoutInfo` String and let me know what it gives.

Comment: Here you go --> I/patronCheckoutInfo: null

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
JSONArray patronCheckoutInfo= obj2.optJSONArray("patronCheckoutInfo");
if(patronCheckoutInfo){
        for (int i = 0; i < invitations.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject patronCheckoutInfoObject= patronCheckoutInfo.getJSONObject(i);
        }
}
```