# os.NetowrkOnMainThreadException service

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

I read a few tutorials (one at tutorial point, and one at developer.android.com) and thought I was doing this correctly to avoid having this error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`  However, I am still getting it despite having my network connection in the service started by calling startService (which happens when I click the start button in mainactivity, I didn't add the layout xml, but the onClick method has been set)

I will try to paste relevant code here:

## main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startService(View view) {
       startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
    }

    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

## Service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }*/

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        KClient client = new KClient(8096);

        if(client.openConn("login","password")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"failed to connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

## manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.frizzled.MyService">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


</manifest>
```

Comment: If you are using service to make network call, then it would be easier if you use AsyncTask

Comment: In the end, I don't want my application to have a UI, so do I need to use an AsyncTask as well from within the service?

Comment: You need service / asycn task take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36099088/4597347

Comment: No need of service asycTask itself is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStartCommand()` is called on the main application thread. A `Service` does not have any threads of its own. Certain specific subclasses of `Service`, like `IntentService`, do. Whether you should use `IntentService`, or whether you should continue using `Service` but fork your own thread, would depend a lot on what you are planning on doing with the network connection:

- if the work will be fairly transactional (open the connection, do some work, close the connection, go away), use `IntentService`, with your networking work in `onHandleIntent()`
- if the work will more open-ended in terms of timing, like a chat client, use your own thread (managed by a `Service` or not, depending on whether you need other features of the `Service`, such as process importance)

Answer (score 1):

Services are not run on a separate thread, they run on the UI thread.  You need to move this to an AsyncTask or Thread owned by the service.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you.  I thought the service was run on it's own thread and just started by the main thread.  Thank you